# access variables / array in media.phtml on description.phtml

Tags: product

I created variable in my `media.phtml` say some array `$abc= array(1,2,3)`. Now, when I do `print_r($abc)` in my `description.phtml`,
it gives blank value. I was guessing can I access that or have to call same function twice( function that creates array).

Is there any way to do that?

In `view.phtml`, `media.phtml` is writted before `description.phtml` so logical it must give value there also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should not declare variables in phtml files unless they are for local usage.
In your case you can use a helper that generates the array and you can use it everywhere.
Something like this:

```
<?php 
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function getSomething()
    {
         return array(1,2,3);
    }
}
```

then you can use that in any template:

```
$abc = Mage::helper('[module]')->getSomething();
```

if you have complex logic behind the generation of this array and you don't want to call the logic twice for performance reasons you can cache the result in a member variable in the helper. Since helpers are singletons you won't have the performance problem.
Something like this:

```
<?php 
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
    protected $something;
    public function getSomething()
    {
         if (is_null($this->something)) {
             $this->something = array(1,2,3);//replace with your custom logic
         }
         return $this->something;
    }
}
```

Now you can use it, same as above but your logic is called only once.

Comment: you said i can "cache the result in a member variable in the helper" how

Comment: That is what i explaine in the second part. The var `something` is for that.